# would_will_should

Tags: grammar

I friend of mine invites me to have dinner to his place and I ask him:

> Me: What would you like me to bring?
>
> My friend:Wine **(should)/ (would)/ (will)** be perfect.

Think that the sentences with "would" and "will" can be expanded like this:

1. If I **brought** wine, it **would** be perfect
   => This sentence is a hypothetical situation as in 2nd conditional sentence, so that this sentence sounds polite and indirect)
2. If I **bring** wine, it **will** be perfect => this sentence is kind of the 1st conditional sentence, so that the sentence sounds direct.

But with **"should"** I don't know if it is the 1st or 2 nd conditional sentence:

3. If I **bring/brought** wine, it **should** be perfect.

Comment: We wouldn't use _should_ in this context.

Comment: Are "would" and "should" are conditional sentences as I explained above?

Comment: *Wine should do it*. would be okay. It means fulfil some condition or criteria. Like making a meal complete, for example.

Answer (score 2):

"Should" in this context seems to suggest that wine ought to be perfect, but isn't.

The speaker is giving an opinion. He believes that wine would be perfect, but recognises that there are unknown factors. He has a strong opinion that everybody should accept wine as a perfect gift, but recognises that some might not agree.

It suggests that wine would be perfect, in an ideal world, but there are other factors that might make it not perfect.

> Wine should be perfect, but my wife is fasting so perhaps a soft drink might be a nice idea.

It is not part of the 1st 2nd 3rd conditional model.

Generally one would not use "should" in this context.

Comment: You said "should" is not part of the conditional model, so are the sentences with "would" and "will" part of the conditional model?

Comment: There is a simplified description (or model) of conditionals: 0: if *present* then *present*.  1st: If *present* then *will future*.  2nd if *past* then *would*  3rd  If *past perfect* then *would have*... It is an incomplete description of conditionals in English, because there are lots of grammatically correct conditionals that don't fit these patterns.  But they are useful to explain that the past tense in a conditional might not refer to the past time.

Comment: I what the conditional sentences are . But I am not sure if my 2 sentences are in form of conditional sentences: 1. If I brought wine, it would be perfect (2nd) & If I bring wine, it will be perfect (1st)

Comment: Those two sentence fit the pattern of 2nd and 1st conditional sentences.  More generally a conditional sentence is any sentence with a condition, even if this condition is implied and not explicit  "I would get a job but I don't have any qualifications".  Is a conditional sentence,  the conditional phrase is implied not explicit. Also "Yes, If you study hard." is a conditional fragment, which might make sense in context.  There is a wide variety of conditional expressions in English.

Comment: "I've bought three loaves- that should be enough". Here "should" expresses the speaker's assumption. It has the same meaning as "I think that it is likely that 3 loaves are enough."Why can't I use "should" with the same meaning as in loaves example:
"If I bring/brought wine, it should be perfect".=" If I bring/brought wine, I think it is likely to be perfect."